# How to set an image as background image on a click?

Tags: android, image, background

I have got an activity that shows a grid view with different images. When clicking on one of those images I want the clicked image to be the background image of another activity.

How can I do that?

This is my activity that shows the grid view:

```
public class HelloGridViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    /**
     * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
     * */
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

//WHAT SHALL I PUT HERE????
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you are loading images in your GridView somehow, then just send same information (URL or file URI) to your second activity using Intent.

Comment: @user1420042 : How is your `GridView` adapter populated? With resource ids or file URI's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the poster didn't (originally) specify exactly whether the other activity was to be opened immediately on click, or if the clicked item's image just needed to be recorded for use later.  The first problem seems more common to me, as in a `GridView` that shows a set of image thumbnails.  The user clicks on that, and a new Activity showing just that item's information comes up.  That thumbnail image maybe goes full screen.  Anyway, maybe that's not what the poster had in mind, but that's my assumption (and probably somebody will eventually find this answer with such a use case in mind).

It also isn't specified how the images are stored, so I'll make assumptions that

1. The `ImageAdapter`'s images are bundled resources of this app
2. We can make some changes to the `ImageAdapter`, to store some data to solve this problem

So, with that, I take a standard `ImageAdapter`, and add one line of code to record the integer resource ID for each ImageView, in the ImageView's `tag` property.  There's many ways to do this, but this is the way I chose.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   /* see code removed at 
       http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html 
    */

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView;
      if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
         imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
         imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
         imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
      } else {
         imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }

      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
      // here we record the resource id of the image, for easy access later
      imageView.setTag(mThumbIds[position]);
      return imageView;
   }

   // references to our images
   private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
         R.drawable.pic1, 
         R.drawable.pic2, 
         R.drawable.pic3, 
         R.drawable.pic4, 
         R.drawable.pic5 
   };
}
```

Then, when the Hello activity has a grid item clicked, I retrieve the image's resource id and pass it as an `Intent` extra (HelloGridViewActivity.java):

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

      // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
      gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

      final Context activity = this;

      gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object tag = v.getTag();
            if (tag instanceof Integer) {
               // we stored a reference to the thumbnail image in the ImageView's tag property
               Intent i = new Intent(activity, AnotherActivity.class);
               Integer resourceId = (Integer)tag;
               i.putExtra("backgroundImage", resourceId);
               startActivity(i);
            }
         }
      });
   }
```

And finally, when the new activity (`AnotherActivity`) is opened, we retrieve that intent extra, and decode it as an integer resource id, and set it as the background image with a fullscreen `ImageView` (AnotherActivity.java):

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.setContentView(R.layout.another);

      Intent i = getIntent();
      //String bgImage = i.getExtras().getString("backgroundImage");
      int resId = i.getExtras().getInt("backgroundImage");

      try {
         ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgImage);
         // Another alternative, if the intent extra stored the resource 'name',
         //   and not the integer resource id
         //Class<?> c = R.drawable.class;
         //background.setImageResource(c.getDeclaredField(bgImage).getInt(c));
         background.setImageResource(resId);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

I also show above some commented out code, if for some reason you need to pass a **string** name of an image resource, instead of an **integer** resource code.  The commented out code looks up the resource id for the given image name.  According to the resource names used in my ImageAdapter, a sample string name to pass might be `"pic1"`.  If you do this, of course, the calling Activity (HelloGridViewActivity) needs to encode the Intent extra as a String, not an integer.

Comment: Hey Nate, thank you! There is only one more problem I have: The activity (AnotherActivity) is my startup activity. When launching my app it crashes because it tries to get an intent which has not been send. Any solutions??

Comment: @user1420042, We need some more information on how your activities are used.  Your startup activity (AnotherActivity) ... does it only change its background image when the app starts up?  If so, then the other answer for using `SharedPreferences` is probably what you want.  Or does this startup activity also get navigated back to when the app runs?  And when this happens, is the background image supposed to change?  Please add your clarifications to the original question, so it's easy for everyone to see exactly what you are trying to do.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nate what I want is that the user off the application can change the background of an activity (anotheractivity). This background image should be saved so that the user, when opening the app, sees the background image he set before. it should work like a settings preference you see on any phone where you can set your background image. I just want to have this capability inside my app.

Comment: @user1420042, then i think you should use banananuttruffles' solution.  SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

Get the resource ID of the image you want as the BG and save it to preferences.

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        saveImageId(position);
    }

private void saveImageId(int position) {
    int id = getImageId(); // get the R.drawable.* id of the image. You should be able to figure this out.
    Editor ed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    ed.putInt("bg_image_id", id);
    ed.commit();
}
```

Now in your other activity, you can get the image id:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int id = prefs.getInt("bg_image_id", R.drawable.default_background); //Get image id, use default background if there isn't one.
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background_layout);
mLayout.setBackgroundResource(id);
```

Good luck

Comment: The SharedPreferences should be used for application preferences, not temporary data. A global static variable in the GridView activity to store the resource ID of the image that was clicked on would be a better solution.

Comment: "// get the R.drawable.* id of the image. You should be able to figure this out." And if I don't figure it out

Comment: @shanet : The suggestion in your comment is no more efficient than the answer from BananaNutTruffles. Have neither of you heard of `Intent` extras? The OP want's to start a new `Activity`....it's not a difficult question to answer.

Comment: It is an application preference. Is it not? He's not starting a new activity. He's setting the background for whenever that activity is opened. Which is why I opted for shared prefs. Naturally, Intent extras are used for a one time occurrence.

Comment: And user, if you don't figure it out, you'll have to post the code for how you set the image views resources. It should be based on position.

Comment: @BananaNutTruffles : Read the question... "When clicking on one of those images I want the clicked image to be **the background image of another activity.**"

Comment: @MisterSquonk Yes. He never mentioned opening the other activity. It implies a pref. Not an intent.

Comment: @MisterSquonk No need to be rude. OP did not say he would be starting a new activity or bringing an existing one to the foreground so Intent extras are not the way to go here.

Comment: @BananaNutTruffles prefs are something should be stored over multiple runs of the app. Given the context, it's reasonable to assume that the app will not be storing the resource ID over multiple runs. Thus, doing multiple read/writes to a pref file is less efficient than a single global static variable, but given the infrequency at which this will happen, this argument is essentially moot.

Comment: @shanet hmm. I still see it as a pref. I'd expect the background to always be the background once changed. But this argument is moot, it just different interpretations of an unclear question posted by a 1st timer. xD

Comment: @BananaNutTruffles Good point. Given more information, I would probably use a global static and then save to the pref file when the activity using the selected image is destroyed or write it to the saved instance state of that activity. Either one works.

Comment: @shanet : Sorry, it wasn't my intention to be rude, my comment was meant to be 'tongue in cheek'. :) From the last comments, I concur that the question isn't well worded and we've all perhaps interpreted it differently. My interpretation was the `onItemClick(...)` method would start a new `Activity` immediately rather than try to 'persist' the choice of image. I'll back off from this question now - without clarification from the OP, there doesn't seem to be a clear answer.

Comment: @@BananaNutTruffles : See my above comment to shanet. Agreed, the question is unclear.

Comment: @MisterSquonk yep. We're all correct, relatively. It's crazy how 3 different patterns came out of this post xD