# Keep grid view selected item highlighted after focus lost

Tags: android

I have a grid view in my activity. I have set the item highlight color of the grid view with `GridView.setSelector()`.

XML

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/category_edit_grid_item_size"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Code

```
gridView.setSelector(R.color.theme_primary);
```

When I select an item, it gets highlighted in `R.color.theme_primary`. But as soon as I move to another input element in the activity (say I touched on an edit text), the grid view highlight goes away.

How can I keep the highlight even after grid view looses focus?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598301/set-background-in-gridview-by-item-position

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a custom state for the item that you want to keep highlighted.  You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336060/android-how-to-add-a-custom-button-state) for how to add a state.  After adding the state simply add logic for determining when to enable/disable that state.

Comment: This would work. But I hope I would find a simpler way