# change background resource of an image in the gridview in android

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview

here am trying to change the background resource for the image, am success in that, but the problem is, when i clicking on all the items in the gridview every item has changes in the background resource, my question is if i click on item which is 0 position it has to change the background resource image, and again if i click on the item which is in 1 position it has to change the background resource and as well as a image on 0 position has to set normal image like without background resource comes to normal state.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View vv, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        vv.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);


    }
```

Provide me to set only one selected item has to change the image. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need modify your adapter to set background for checked items. For Example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // creating view

    if(item.isChecked()){
        veiw.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to modify the Adapter and for that i will refer you to this question here 
[How to set an image as background image on a click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790984/how-to-set-an-image-as-background-image-on-a-click)

Check the accepted answer and do it as described and you are good to go